# Conversion of tree structures

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working on an issue for my QueryBuilder JavaScript library (https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/issues/59).

The objective is to fill the builder from a SQL statement. To do that I use https://github.com/forward/sql-parser to convert the WHERE clause to an AST.

Now my problem is that I need to convert this AST (which is a kind of Binary Tree) to the internal format of QueryBuilder (I don't know the technical name). But I'm dumb and I can't find a working algorithm.

So I'm here to find someone who is good at this ! I just need the main algorithm to convert the data structure, converting the values and operators format won't be a problem.

Notes:

- The depth is not limited
- Group conditions are (of course) only AND and OR
- While the order of rules is not important, it should be preserved

The input SQL is (test case) :

```
name LIKE "Mistic%" 
AND price BETWEEN 100 AND 200 
AND (
  category IN(1,2)
  OR parent <= 0
) 
AND id is not null
```

This is the output of the SQL Parser :

```
{
  left: {
    left: {
      left: {
        left: {
          value: 'name'
        },
        operation: 'LIKE',
        right: {
          value: 'Mistic%'
        },
      },
      operation: 'AND',
      right: {
        left: {
          value: 'price'
        },
        operation: 'BETWEEN',
        right: {
          value: [
            {
              value: 100
            },
            {
              value: 200
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    operation: 'AND',
    right: {
      left: {
        left: {
          value: 'category'
        },
        operation: 'IN',
        right: {
          value: [
            {
              value: 1
            },
            {
              value: 2
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      operation: 'OR',
      right: {
        left: {
          value: 'parent'
        },
        operation: '<=',
        right: {
          value: 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  operation: 'AND',
  right: {
    left: {
      value: 'id'
    },
    operation: 'is not',
    right: {
      value: null
    }
  }
}
```

This is the data structure I need :

```
{
  condition: 'AND',
  rules: [
    {
      id: 'name',
      operator: 'like',
      value: 'Mistic%'
    },
    {
      id: 'price',
      operator: 'between',
      value: [100, 200]
    },
    {
      condition: 'OR',
      rules: [
        {
          id: 'category',
          operator: 'in',
          value: [1, 2]
        },
        {
          id: 'parent',
          operator: 'less_or_equal',
          value: 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 'id',
      operator: 'not_null',
      value: null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it working, here is the pseudo code:

```
var out = {
  condition: null
  rules: []
}
var curr = out

function flatten(node, level)
  if node.operation = 'AND' or node.operation = 'OR' then
    if level > 0 and curr.condition != node.operation then
      curr.rules.push({
        condition: null
        rules: []
      })
      curr = curr.rules.end()
    end if

    curr.condition = node.operation

    level++;

    var next = curr
    flatten(node.right, level)

    curr = next
    flatten(node.left, level)
  else
    curr.rules.push({
      id: node.left.value
      operator: node.operation
      value: node.right.value
    })
  end if
end function

flatten(parsed, 0)
```

It's a self calling recursive function creating subgroups when the operator changes between AND and OR, and small bit a trickery to work in the right subgroup when flattening the left and the right parts.